# SQL Select records for this week and the next week

Tags: php, sql, pdo

http://gyazo.com/bc0f6794c260fdb97ee79e016abd0a11

the *dag* column means day or date and contains a datetime.
How can I select the records for this week and the next week, using the *dag* column?

I've got the following working code in PHP, but it also selected a dozen records from last year, but I don't want that.

```
$sth = $dbh -> prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . $cfg -> db_user . '_veld_wedstrijden WHERE thuisteam LIKE "'.$cfg -> db_user.'%" OR uitteam LIKE "'.$cfg -> db_user.'%" AND dag >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY ORDER BY dag ASC');
$sth -> execute();
```

The last bit of the query is where it selects them by the date.

Comment: Your first LIKE is what is picking up the old records

Comment: Ah I see what I did wrong here, thank you.

Comment: No problem, if it fixed the problem then you are welcome to answer this yourself or consider checking @Tim Dev's answer out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your make sure you use parentheses around your  `(thuis OR uit)` selection.

Second of all your current date operation is: get all matches with a date bigger than (today + 7 days).

You said in title you want all matches for this week and the next week. So from today 'till 14 days.

Use [between](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) like this

```
SELECT * FROM ' . $cfg -> db_user . '_veld_wedstrijden 
WHERE 
    ( thuisteam LIKE "'.$cfg -> db_user.'%"  OR uitteam LIKE "'.$cfg -> db_user.'%")
AND 
    dag BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 WEEK
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks very much, learned something new today about between and parentheses :)

Comment: Just one note - it is better to pass dates to queries so that it could be cached correctly.